# Why PaddingValue not working in Jetpack compose NavHost

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a BottomNavigation that has paddingValue. I have a splash screen in the app and after that, I have HomeScreen HomeScreen. When I want to navigate a screen that has not shown bottom navigation to a screen that shows it, My app is refreshed. how can i fix it?

```
 MyKuyaClientTheme(darkTheme = false) {
                if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "development" || BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "staging") {
                    SensorListenerCompose {
                        clientNavigator.navigate(LoggerDestination.route())
                    }
                }

                SystemBroadcastReceiver(Constants.UPDATE_UNRATED_JOBS) { intent ->
                    intent?.let {
                        val request = it.getParcelableArrayExtra("unratedjobs")?.get(0) as Request
                        val isInRatingJobs = it.getBooleanExtra("inratingjob", false)
                        if (!isInRatingJobs)
                            clientNavigator.navigate(
                                JobRatingDestination.createJobRatingRoute(
                                    Gson().toJson(request)
                                )
                            )
                    }
                }
                Surface(
                    color = AppColor.ThemeColor.BACKGROUND,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            ConnectivityStatus()
                            **ClientScaffold(clientNavigator)**
                        }
                        val gpsEnable by locationHelper.gpsProviderState
                        if (!gpsEnable) {
                            MakeSureLocEnable(this@MainActivity)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

```
fun ClientScaffold(clientNavigator: ClientNavigator?) {
    var showBottomBar by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
    val sheetState =
        rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, SwipeableDefaults.AnimationSpec)
    val bottomSheetNavigator = rememberBottomSheetNavigatorFix(sheetState)
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    navController.navigatorProvider += bottomSheetNavigator

    systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = Color.Transparent)
    LaunchedEffect(navController) {
        clientNavigator?.destinations?.collectLatest { event ->
            when (event) {
                is NavigatorEvent.NavigateUp -> {
                    sheetState.hide()
                    navController.navigateUp()
                }
                is NavigatorEvent.PopBackStack -> {
                    sheetState.hide()
                    navController.popBackStack()
                }
                is NavigatorEvent.Directions -> {
                    navController.navigate(
                        event.destination,
                        event.builder
                    )
                }

            }
        }
    }
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        bottomSheetNavigator = bottomSheetNavigator,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = {
                MyKuyaBottomNavigation(navController)
            },
            content = { paddingValues ->
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = SplashDestination.route(),
                    **modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = paddingValues),**
                ) {
                    addComposableDestinations(navController)
                }
            }
        )
    }

}
```

I think it's to do with changing the paddingValue value

Comment: what you mean app is refreshed, You mean your padding values applied instantly?

Comment: When I used paddingValues(Even when I set a Log for paddingValues) the navHost recomposed and the start destination is called

Comment: Use padding values manually instead of scaffold padding values. Maybe this solve your problem.

Comment: How can I do that?